# How to add setup delay between RS485 line-drive and TX in Linux kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, rs485

I have a SAMA5D3 board which supports rs485 mode on its USART port.

The chip has built-in support for "time-guard" e.g. the delay between de-asserting the line drive (here RTS) after the last sent bit. (it is a long stop bit)

But the datasheet doesn't mention any set-up delay (time between asserting the line drive (here RTS) and starting the transmission of the start bit).

I looked at `drivers/serial/tty/serial/atmel_serial.c` and tried to inject a `udelay()` function into the `atmel_start_tx()` with no luck.

Any ideas how one could "teach" the driver how to do the setup delay?

[image: rs485modeDatasheet]

---

With Linux terms, `delay_rts_before_send` is not read/handled by the `atmel_serial.c` driver, only `delay_rts_after_send`. https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/serial/serial-rs485.html

Comment: Does it actually write the correct value to the "timeguard" register? In Figure 44-36 above it looks like the value is in baud rate clock periods (e.g. the "TG = 4" spans 4 baud rate clock periods), but in Linux the `delay_rts_before_send` and `delay_rts_after_send` values are specified in milliseconds. The `atmel_config_rs485()` function in `atmel_serial.c` looks like it writes the `delay_rts_after_send` value directly to the register without converting the value from milliseconds to baud rate clock periods.

Comment: "*But the datasheet doesn't mention any set-up delay ...*" -- Because there isn't any. There's simply a delay of a *single* (1) bit time after RTS has been asserted that the transmission commences. That's what the `1` (that you highlighted) in Figure 44-36 illustrates. That `1` is not configurable as you want to believe. That `1` has nothing to do with "timeguard". Hence, no software interface. If your line-driver or transceiver cannot respond quickly enough (i.e. within the one-bit time), then you will have to use a slower baudrate.

Comment: thanks @IanAbbott, I will have a look into the conversion!

Comment: Hi @sawdust,  yes all what you say is the reason for my question. I was thinking about something like a SW delay with udelay in strat_tx

Comment: "*A SW delay*" is not going to affect a HW-controlled signal. If you insist on a such a delay, then you would have to abandon this built-in RS-485 feature, and instead implement full SW control of the RTS line in the USART driver. But your post really reeks like an ***XY question***. Are you having issues with a cheap/slow transceiver? Maybe you need to use a faster transceiver and/or slower baudrate?